# Add Working Days to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my quest to construct a function that can calculate the date after x working days I came across this function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AddBusinessDays] (@Date date,@n INT) 
RETURNS DATE AS BEGIN 
DECLARE @d INT;
SET @d=4-SIGN(@n)*(4-DATEPART(DW,@Date));
RETURN DATEADD(D,@n+((ABS(@n)+@d-2)/5)*2*SIGN(@n)-@d/7,@Date) END
```

This function works however I need to link it with my holiday table so that it can omit specific holidays in my country. When I run it with today's date (26-04-2017) I get this date after 20 working days 24-05-2017, so it omitted only the weekends. How do I modify it so that it also skips the holidays?
Apologies if I am sending too many requests for one problem. I am a beginner in SQL. Thanks

Comment: Where are you specifying the holidays or referring to ?

Comment: can you post a few examples of the input and the expected output, showing your holiday table?

Comment: Use a calendar table to avoid these hard to read and maintain calculations.

Comment: That function may "work" but can you decipher it? It makes my head spin with all that craziness.

Comment: You seem to be working in exactly the wrong direction. I see you've commented on your previous question that your "holiday table" *is* in fact a full calendar table. You *should* learn to use it rather than continuing with this procedural approach. In SQL (to generalize), set-based = good, procedural = bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on hard to understand calculations wouldn't it be easier to explicitly have your working dates and select from there? For example:

```
DECLARE @NthWorkingDay INT = 33;

DECLARE @holidays TABLE
    (
      holiday DATE ,
      [description] VARCHAR(500)
    );
INSERT  @holidays
        ( holiday, description )
VALUES  ( '20170519', '...' ),
        ( '20170501', '...' ),
        ( '20170611', '...' ),
        ( '20170704', '...' );


DECLARE @sunday INT ,
    @saturday INT;
-- 1/1/2000 is a known date - Saturday

SET @saturday = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEFROMPARTS(2000, 1, 1));
SET @sunday = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEFROMPARTS(2000, 1, 2));

WITH    tally
          AS ( SELECT TOP 5000
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t1.object_id ) AS N
               FROM     master.sys.all_columns t1
                        CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns t2
             ),
        dates ( theDate )
          AS ( SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
               FROM     tally
             ),
        workDates ( workingDay, workingDate )
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY theDate ) ,
                        theDate
               FROM     dates
               WHERE    DATEPART(WEEKDAY, theDate) NOT IN ( @saturday, @sunday )
                        AND theDate NOT IN ( SELECT holiday
                                             FROM   @holidays )
             )
    SELECT  workingDate
    FROM    workDates
    WHERE   workingDay = @NthWorkingDay;
```

Comment: This wont work as I have lots and lots of data to go through.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "this won't work ... lots and lots ..". The upper part was just a sampling of your data, you would simply use yours instead.

Comment: I have decided to use this other function i created together with my colleague that takes long but figured if it can start around 12 midnight when I get to work it should be done. Thanks for the feedback